# I got Fixnum is deprecated when I ran Ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rubygems

When I run my project, i got these warning. Do you have any idea about that?

Thanks

It has more than 100 rows, i just added one.

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.9/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/html_elements.rb:17: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

`Fixnum` is deprecated indeed.

Ruby 2.4 unifies `Fixnum` and `Bignum` into `Integer`.

It seems gem `watir-webdriver` is not adapted to Ruby 2.4.

In fact last release is **0.9.9** from **November 09, 2016**.

Comment: `watir-webdriver` is deprcated.  Here's a link to `watir`: https://github.com/watir/watir

Comment: thank you. when i install last version of watir and selenium, it is fixed.